# Framework classes which natively support deconstruction

Tags: c#, .net, c#-7.0

Since .NET 4.7 `Tuple` and `ValueTuple` seems natively(without custom extension deconstruction methods) to support a deconstruction.

I'm curious whether there are any .NET classes(except Tuple and ValueTuple), which natively support deconstruction?

Comment: A quick search turns up [Deconstructors for non-tuple types in C# 7.0](https://andrewlock.net/deconstructors-for-non-tuple-types-in-c-7-0/)

Comment: @stuartd, did I miss something? That article makes no mention of deconstructors in other framework classes, as far as I can see.

Comment: Probably not -- you could grep over the codebase/reflect over the classes to find out for sure. [There might be more in the future](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/26209). Even so, extension methods seem quite obviously the way to go for most types.

Comment: @DavidArno I took the sentence _"you can add deconstructors to all your classes"_ to mean deconstructors were supported by all classes. My bad, I missed the "natively" part.. (I was wondering how extension methods would even work with deconstructors, and found [this article](http://structuredsight.com/2016/08/29/c-7-additions-deconstructors/) explaining it)

Comment: Even Tuple and ValueTuple deconstruction is implemented as [extension methods](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/4fe5d4620bffb6ed243843ed247a578ea7936c73/src/System.ValueTuple/ref/System.ValueTuple.cs)

Answer (score 3):

Searching [corefx on Github](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=deconstruct&type=) suggests that it's been added to [`DictionaryEntry`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/103639b6ff5aa6ab6097f70732530e411817f09b/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Collections/DictionaryEntry.cs) and [`KeyValuePair`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/103639b6ff5aa6ab6097f70732530e411817f09b/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Collections/Generic/KeyValuePair.cs) only.

Comment: With `(object str, object i) = new DictionaryEntry("555", 555);` I become compile error. With `KeyValuePair` the same. :(

Comment: Target version is 4.7

Comment: Looks like it's a "coming soon" addition then.

Comment: I'm more interested in [this result](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/4fe5d4620bffb6ed243843ed247a578ea7936c73/src/System.ValueTuple/ref/System.ValueTuple.cs#L193) in the search. Even ValueTuple deconstruction is an extension method

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, it's interesting!